# How to register service from external nuget package using Autofac?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

I am trying to add middleware from external nuget packege but Autofac cannot register it.

```
app.UseCustomDataMiddleware();
```

This extension method comes from nuget package. Any ideas how to register it?

Comment: Can you go look what the UseCustomDataMiddleware method does? Find the project's source, github, documentation... anything, several tools will also let you go look at the implementation by doing in place decompilation. Then register the same dependencies in Autofac without the extension method.